# Variable should be an int, but AttributeError claims it's a str

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python keeps giving me an "`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'`" on the line `Words[Check0n].pop()`.

Originally, I tried to solve this by turning `Check` and `Check0` into `int`s and equaling `Checkn` and `Check0n` to those.

Since that didn't work, I checked if `Check0n`'s value was an `int` by using `print(type(Check0n) is int)` twice. Both printed `True`, so I really don't get why it keeps giving the same error it would give if `Check0n` were a string, when it clearly is not.

What I want the program to do is to test for "a" inside of the list. Then, it should test for "thing" in the next spot in the list. If "thing" is there, then it should delete "thing" from that spot in the list, and replace the "a" in the former spot with "a thing". If you were to type in "a stuff", I would want those to remain separated in the list as "a", "stuff".

```
def Sentence_Processing():
    Sentence = input("Enter a sentence:")
    Sentence_0 = Sentence.replace(".", " .")
    Sentence_1 = Sentence_0.replace(",", " ,")
    Words = Sentence_1.split()
    print(Words)
    for Word in Words:
        Word0 = str.lower(Word)
        if Word0 == "a":
            Check = Words.index(Word)
            Check0 = Check+1
            Checkn = int(Check)
            Check0n = int(Check0)
            print(type(Check0n) is int)
            if Words[Check0n] == "thing":
                print(type(Check0n) is int)
                Words[Check0n].pop()
                Words[Checkn] = "a thing"
                print("Did all of it")
            print("Passed")
```

Note that the program is to big for me to paste the entire thing.

Comment: Words[Check0n] is a string, string does not have pop method

Comment: If you're trying to remove an item from the words list you can do Words.pop(<item_index>)

Comment: @Pawel Kordowski The error message pretty much stated that.

Comment: @junnytony Thanks, it's giving me new errors now

Comment: _"Note that the program is to big for me to paste the entire thing. "_ - we never want you to post the whole thing. Instead, reduce the problem down to the smallest lines of code that reproduce the problem. See http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The unusual capitalization and underscores in your code made it much harder to read than it could have been.  Most Python developers follow the semi-official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (a.k.a. "PEP 8").  If your code conforms to that style --- especially the Guide's [naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) --- it will be much more readable to other Python programmers (and you are more likely to get helpful replies from them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"...it keeps giving the same error it would give if `Check0n` was a string..."

No it isn't.  It's giving you the error you would get if `Words[Check0n]` were a string... which it is.  `Words` is a list of strings, and `Words[Check0n]` is one of them.

You can demonstrate this by splitting your problem line:

```
Words[Check0n].pop()
```

...into two:

```
oops = Words[Check0n]
print(repr(oops))
oops.pop()
```

The first and second lines will work just fine, and you will see that `oops` is the string `'thing'`.  Then you will get the same `AttributeError` as before, except that it will be complaining about the `oops.pop()` line.

Your code has other problems:

1. You are removing items from a collection while "for-each" iterating over it, which is always tricky.  It's hard to reason about, because multiple things are changing at once.
2. Your function does too many things, making it hard to tell where the actual bug(s) are.  Consider at least three functions:

   - `get_sentence_from_user()` returns a string.
   - `prep_sentence(sentence)` fiddles with `,` and `.` characters, and returns the resulting "prepared" string.
   - Use the string's `split` method to split it into a list of words.  (No need to write this one yourself.)
   - `merge_words(words)` *builds a new list* by appending one word at a time, with any occurrences of `'a', 'thing'` merged into the single element `'a thing'`.  It returns the new, possibly shorter list.
3. As noted in comments, if you really want to modify the input list, it's `pop` method removes the *rightmost element*.  To remove some other element, you have to give it the integer index of that element.  (This, by the way, is highly likely to be *slower* than building a new output list, in case you were worried about that.)
4. When you find a word `'a'`, you immediately start working on the next word in the list, without verifying that there *is* a next word.  This will raise an `IndexError`... sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for replying(I hate how the comments post when you hit enter...) I've been working on this code and improving it, the Words.pop(<item_index>) thing really helped me. What you said in 3 was what I was trying to do that was giving errors.